# Ignore sending logs for tracing in .net

Tags: c#, .net, trace, open-telemetry, jaeger

I am using OpenTelemetry to send traces to Jaeger int .net 6 by this code:

```
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .ConfigureResource(configureResource)
        .WithTracing(b =>
        {
            b.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .AddSqlClientInstrumentation()
                .AddOtlpExporter(options => { options.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317"); });
        });
```

the problem is that all the logs using ILogger and all the health checks are sent to Jaeger.
I want to ingnore them.

Comment: You mean filtering logs based on the minimum log level does not work?

Comment: The logging is working fine and are sent to elastic as expected by serilog, but those logs are also sent to Jaeger that I want to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

`AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation` has an overload with [options](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore/README.md#advanced-configuration). You can configure a `Filter` option to filter undesired requests:

```cs
builder.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(options =>
{
    options.Filter = (httpContext) =>
    {
        options.Filter = context => !context.Request.Path.Equals("/health");
    };
})
```

Similarly to AspNetCore instrumentation, the [HttpClientInstrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http/README.md#filter-httpclient-api) has the `FilterHttpRequestMessage` to filter the outgoing requests:

```cs
builder.AddHttpClientInstrumentation(options =>
{
    options.FilterHttpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessage =>
        httpRequestMessage.RequestUri?.PathAndQuery != "/health";
});
```

To stop sending logs, you need to remove the OpenTelemetry logging provider from the `Program.cs` file.

Depending on the format of your `Program` class, it may look like this

```cs
builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry()
```

or this

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddOpenTelemetry())
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you have a reference who to remove logging?

Comment: I did not mean to filter /health url. Inside the application i am calling health check of other services and these health checks are sent to tracing that i want to ignore them @artur

Comment: @HamidNoahdi check the updated answer